# Python regex named groups for multiline match

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this

```
Alabama[STATE]
Auburn (Auburn University)[14]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Huntsville (University of Alabama, Huntsville)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[15]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[15]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[15]
Troy (Troy University)[15]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]
Alaska[STATE]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[15]
Arizona[STATE]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[19]
Prescott (Embry–Riddle Aeronautical University)
Tempe (Arizona State University)
```

I am trying to read the state and university list into two named groups using python regex.
My code is

```
UNIV_LIST = r"(?P<state>(\w)+)\[.*\n(?P<region>(.*?).*)"
RE_COMMIT = re.compile(UNIV_LIST)
text = open(UFILE).read()
each_group = RE_COMMIT.finditer(text)
for rc in each_group:
    state = rc.groups()[0]
    regions = rc.groups()[1]
    print ('State is %s' %(state))
    print ('regions are %s' %(regions))
```

Expected output is

```
State is : Alabama
Regions are : Auburn (Auburn University)[14]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Huntsville (University of Alabama, Huntsville)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[15]
Troy (Troy University)[15]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]
State is : Alaska
Regions are : Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[15]
State is : Arizona
Regions are : Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[19]
Prescott (Embry–Riddle Aeronautical University)
Tempe (Arizona State University)
```

But the current output is

```
UNIV_LIST = r"(?P<state>(\w+))\[edit\]\n(?P<region>(.*))\n+")

State is Alabama
regions are Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
State is Alaska
regions are Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
State is Arizona
regions are Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
```

Any suggestions on how to get the region named group correctly ?

[EDIT]
The actual text is

```
Alabama[STATE]
Auburn (Auburn University)[14]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Huntsville (University of Alabama, Huntsville)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[15]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[15]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[15]
Montgomery (Alabama State University, Huntingdon College, Auburn University at Montgomery, H. Councill Trenholm State Technical College,     Faulkner University)
Troy (Troy University)[15]
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[6][17]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]
Alaska[STATE]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[15]
Arizona[STATE]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[19]
Prescott (Embry–Riddle Aeronautical University)
Tempe (Arizona State University)
Tucson (University of Arizona)
Arkansas
Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouachita Baptist University)[15]
Conway (Central Baptist College, Hendrix College, University of Central  Arkansas)[15]
Fayetteville (University of Arkansas)[20]
Jonesboro (Arkansas State University)[21]
Magnolia (Southern Arkansas University)[15]
Monticello (University of Arkansas at Monticello)[15]
Russellville (Arkansas Tech University)[15]
Searcy (Harding University)[18]
California[STATE]
```

the below regex:

```
UNIV_LIST = r"(?P<state>^(\w+\[STATE\]))\r?\n?(?P<region>((^[^[]+)(\[\d+\])?(?!\[STATE\])$\r?\n?)+)"
```

Is provided the most of the expected result but is missing some regions

```
State is : Alabama
Regions are : Auburn (Auburn University)[14]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Huntsville (University of Alabama, Huntsville)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[15]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[15]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[15]
Montgomery (Alabama State University, Huntingdon College, Auburn University at Montgomery, H. Councill Trenholm State Technical College,     Faulkner University)
Troy (Troy University)[15]
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[6][17]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]
State is : Alaska
Regions are : Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[15]
State is : Arizona
Regions are : Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[19]
Prescott (Embry–Riddle Aeronautical University)
Tempe (Arizona State University)
```

I get the result but

```
Montgomery (Alabama State University, Huntingdon College, Auburn University at Montgomery, H. Councill Trenholm State Technical College,     Faulkner University)
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[6][17]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]
```

are missing.
Any suggestion on what is wrong ?

[EDIT]

```
UNIV_LIST = r"(?P<state>^(\w+\s*\w*\[edit\]))\r?\n?(?P<region>((^[^[]+)(\[\d+\]){0,}?(?!\[edit\])$\r?\n?)+)"
```

This handles states with two words like New Mexico.
But there is one case which still fails

```
Pomona (Cal Poly Pomona, WesternU)[9][10][11] and formerly Pomona College
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: What is a region?

Comment: Can you give your current output and expected output?

Comment: i have updated with expected result and current result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex work.

```
UNIV_LIST = r"(?P<state>^(\w+\[STATE\]))\r?\n?(?P<region>((^[^[]+)(\[\d+\]){0,}?(?!\[STATE\])$\r?\n?)+)"
RE_COMMIT = re.compile(UNIV_LIST,re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
each_group = RE_COMMIT.finditer(text)
for rc in each_group:
    print('State is : %s' %(rc.group('state')))
    print('Region are : %s' %rc.group('region'))
    print('-'*40)
```

### Output

```
State is : Alabama[STATE]
Region are : Auburn (Auburn University)[14]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Huntsville (University of Alabama, Huntsville)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[15]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[15]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[15]
Troy (Troy University)[15]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[18]

----------------------------------------
State is : Alaska[STATE]
Region are : Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[15]

----------------------------------------
State is : Arizona[STATE]
Region are : Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[19]
Prescott (Embry–Riddle Aeronautical University)
Tempe (Arizona State University)
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you please suggest what is missing in the regex - it's missing some string,

Comment: add a `{0,}` after the capture group of `[]`. see my updated answer.

Comment: HI Aaron, thanks for the help. It's working now except one case where there are additional word after [\d] in the string. can you please help.

Comment: If there are additional word after `[\d]`, you can just add `\w+` to match it.